# Phalcon behaviours not working

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to get some Phalcon PHP behaviour going, but it's not working in my model as expected. Here's the initialize function of my model:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->addBehavior(
        new Timestampable(
            [
                'beforeCreate' => [
                    'field'  => 'created_at',
                    'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                ]
            ]
        )
    );

    $this->addBehavior(
        new Timestampable(
            [
                'beforeCreate' => [
                    'field'  => 'updated_at',
                    'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                ]
            ]
        )
    );
}
```

This does not save the timestamps to the database when I create a new instance in my code. The lock is saved like this:

```
$lock = new TradesLocks();
$lock->trade_id = $id;
$lock->save();
```

I've gone over the PhalconPHP docs and also cannot see what I'm doing wrong. How come it does not behave like expected?

Answer (score 0):

You sure you have those fields exists in model and if you added it recently that you refreshed metadata?

Comment: I have `public $created_at` and `public $updated_at` - the fields do exist in the database (currently they get the NULL value). How do I refresh metadata?

Comment: Depends on your metadata adapter - if it's files, clear files, ifi t's memcache/redis clear memcache/redis, if it's memory then you don't need to do anything, except if you use annotations metadata - then you obviously need to add such annotation.

Comment: I guess I'm using the standard metadata adapter. How can I check?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simple solution for TimeStamps in your table records. I've been using this method and its works well.

1) Create a trait in your library folder:

```
<?php
namespace Core\Traits;
trait TimeStampable
{
   public function beforeValidationOnCreate()
   {
      $this -> createdAt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   }

   public function beforeUpdate()
   {
      $this -> updatedAt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   }
}
```

2) Go to your Model (or ModelBase class if you use one). Import the trait and use it.

```
<?php

namespace Core\Models;

use \Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Core\Traits\TimeStampable;

class TradesLocks extends Model
{
    use TimeStampable;

    //Other code goes here...
}
```

3) Thats all. If perform an operation in one of the events (Model::beforeValidationOnCreate, Model::beforeUpdate), you can do this:

```
public function beforeValidationOncreate()
{
    //This makes sure the createdAt field gets the timestamp
    parent::initialize();

    //Other custom operations
    $this -> active = 'Y';
}
```

Hope this helps...